# PHP, MySQL GET_LOCK() with autocommit off

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a really dumb question but I was just wondering if you set autocommit off for MySQL and then try to acquire a lock, do you have to then commit after getting the lock for the lock to stay?

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$q = 'SELECT GET_LOCK("lockName", 10)';

$res = $mysqli->query($q);

list($acquiredLock) = $res->fetch_row();


if($acquiredLock) {
  $mysqli->commit();
}
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If `GET_LOCK` returns 1 (success), then the session has obtained the lock.

The lock will continue to be held by the session independent of `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.